# ElasticSearch JAVAFX and JAVA, NoNodeAvailable NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available

Tags: java, elasticsearch, javafx

I saw many answers to my problem but none of them helped, so I'm trying to find some help.
I'm facing this problem for a few weeks now :/

I'm trying to run Java code that creates ElasticSearch connection and try to load FXML file.

ElasticSearch version: 6.4.2 (I know it is old, but this is the version my code support).
runs of port 9200 in localhost, seems to work just fine.
I hava 1 node.
Runs as service.

Java: 1.8 (Very old code).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arRe8.png)

```
# ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
#
# NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
#       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
#       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
#
# The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
# the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.
#
# Please consult the documentation for further information on configuration options:
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/index.html
#
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
cluster.name: VarmerES
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
node.name: varmer
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
#node.attr.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
#path.data: /path/to/data
#
# Path to log files:
#
#path.logs: /path/to/logs
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
#bootstrap.memory_lock: true
#
# Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
# on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
# limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
#network.host: 192.168.0.1
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
#http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when new node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
#discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["host1", "host2"]
#
# Prevent the "split brain" by configuring the majority of nodes (total number of master-eligible nodes / 2 + 1):
#
#discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 
#
# For more information, consult the zen discovery module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Gateway -----------------------------------
#
# Block initial recovery after a full cluster restart until N nodes are started:
#
#gateway.recover_after_nodes: 3
#
# For more information, consult the gateway module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Require explicit names when deleting indices:
#
#action.destructive_requires_name: true
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdfMs.png)

ElasticSearch Configuration:

My code which creates the ElasticSearch connection:

```
 public void initSever() throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    Settings settings = Settings.builder().put("cluster.name", "VarmerES")
            .put("client.transport.ignore_cluster_name", true)
            // .put("node.client", true)
            .put("client.transport.sniff", true).build();

    client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings)
            .addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9200));
    System.out.println("Elastic Search Ready- client: " + client);
}
```

The error I'm getting:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Varmer/target/classes/MainForm.fxml

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2625)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2603)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2435)
    at gui.ScreensController.loadScreen(ScreensController.java:69)
    at gui.Main.start(Main.java:41)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:919)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$11(PlatformImpl.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(PlatformImpl.java:418)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:417)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:175)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{ed6tM9UkTCWZyAXklViE4Q}{localhost}{127.0.0.1:9200}]]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:349)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:247)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportProxyClient.execute(TransportProxyClient.java:60)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.doExecute(TransportClient.java:381)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:407)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:396)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient$IndicesAdmin.execute(AbstractClient.java:1254)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:46)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.get(ActionRequestBuilder.java:53)
    at storageUtils.ESUtils.loadSimWSimType(ESUtils.java:817)
    at gui.MainFormController.loadSimWeightsSimType(MainFormController.java:518)
    at gui.MainFormController.initialize(MainFormController.java:188)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2573)
    ... 13 more
```

this is my JavaFX function which fails on myloader.load():

```
public boolean loadScreen(String name, String resource)
{
    try
    {
        URL res=Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(resource);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(""));
        FXMLLoader myloader = new FXMLLoader (res);
        Parent loadScreen = myloader.load();
        ControlledScreen myScreenController = myloader.getController();
        myScreenController.setScreenParent(this);
        addScreen(name, loadScreen);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

If any more data needed I will provide,
Thank you.

I tried to establish connection to elasticsearch.

Comment: `cluster.name` in your client configuration should match the one in your server configuration, i.e. `VarmerES`

Comment: Sorry I uploaded the wrong image, fixed it on the post.

Comment: I did connect to the VarmerES and still the same error.

Comment: The exception originates in your `MainFormController` class (see the root cause in the stack trace). It may help to post relevant code from there.

Answer (score 0):

After many test we found out that even that the elasticsearch port is 9200 we need to access it via java in port 9300.
seems to work for TransportClient on version 6.4.2